# How to package and upload my Cordova App to Windows Store from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, cordova-3

We paid a developer account in Windows Store (enterprise).
We created a Cordova 3.7 app for Windows Phone 8.1 and even we could test directly on a phone with Windows 8.1 from Visual Studio 2013 and everything worked in the hardware.
therefore, We begin to fill in the details for the App We need to publish in the store.

There is a section in which we are asked to upload a packaged App so here We have  the chance of selecting it on the disk.

Our problem is We don't know how to create the pack and where in the disk Visual Studio left it.

We started to search in msdn.microsoft.com and these are the ideas we could get (but still couldn't make a pack):

1) Every where in MSDN they talk about a STORE option on Visual Studio. We can see this option in the ppal menu but all its options are disabled.
But in a forum, after searching a lot, We could figure out that this is normal for Cordova Apps on Visual Studio 2013 because they are considered as Silverlight Apps.
Then We find out again a doc in MSDN about uploading Silverlight Apps to Win Store. They say this kind of Apps must be packed and uploaded by hand.

2) So We focused in find out how to prepare a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app for publishing.
This is a link in MSDN :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655122(v=vs.105).aspx

But a new problem comes out, We don’t have any Package.appxmanifest.xml file in our project but only have aWMAppManifest.xml file. 
We finally find out only Windows Phone 8.1 projects on Visual Studio  have the  Package.appxmanifest.xml file and it seems that my Cordova Project was generated like a kind of a Win Phone 8.0, what is not that bad because we want our App to be supported by Windows P. 8.0 and 8.1  devices.

But at the end of all this journey, we are stuck at the first step again. So we realized we don't know how pack a Windows Phone 8 (Cordova) App in order to be uploaded to Windows Store.
How and where Visual Studio 2013 make the pack and what is the extension name of this file.
The App, as I said, is ok and can be deployed and executed OK in a real phone from Visual Studio (run button)

Sorry, We know the question is large but We wanted to clear what We had reached so you know What We are asking and What We could have done bad just in case.

Thanks in advance, We think a lot of people could profit of the answer of experts in this matter because a summary is needed, the info in MSDN seem disperse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload a Windows Phone Silverlight xap to the Windows Store, only to the Windows Phone store. To upload to the Windows Phone store you won't need the Package.appxmanifest for a Windows Phone 8 app (only for a Windows Phone 8.1 app).

You'll upload the xap file created when you build for release with the normal build process. You don't need to do any further modifications for a Silverlight app.

You can create either Windows Phone or Windows Store apps with [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://aka.ms/cordova)

Comment: Thank you for this summary. So I only have to build and use a supposed xap file that Visual Studio must create. I'll try to find this file, I've been looking for it in some folder in the cordova project created for Windows Phone pLatform but didn't found it so I thought I was doing something wrong.

I'll accept your answer in the meantime because.

Comment: I've just try your advice. What I'm trying to upload is the xap file created by Visual Studio, the App we need to publish is for Windows Phone 8.0 (We suppose this could be installed in a Windows Phone 8.1 device too).
When we select the xap file and submit it to the form Store Portal the message is:

ONLY CAN LOAD .appx, appxbundle or .appxupload.

We've capture image of the form  in Store Portal at that moment.

What is my fault?

Thank you again.

Comment: Here I could upload the capture of the form http://www.i3net.es/publising-winp8-store.png, I hope this help you to see What's my fault. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your image is of the Windows dashboard. You need to use the Windows Phone dashboard to upload Windows Phone apps. There should be a link to the Windows Phone dashboard at the bottom of the left column. Since there isn't I suspect you haven't set up a Windows Phone account. You should be able to set that up from the root level dashboard (likely https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/dashboard ). You won't need to pay twice, but you'll still need to set up the linked accounts.

Comment: A little confused because when I started to define my App never showed me the important matter of choose between Win or Win Phone store so I didn't realize
Why  was selected by default the Windows Store?
Thanks to your advice now I'm always trying to be aware of the store where I'm uploading my App, but still a problem. 
In  Windows Phone Store (this page: http://www.i3net.es/WinPhoneSumaryPage.png)

If I click Submit App stay here. Msoft forcing me to fill the Tax profile, Payment account , etc. even if I intend to publish the Windows Phone App as a Free App?
Thaks, Happy New Year by the Way

Comment: If I want to publish a Free App on Windows Phone Store are we force  anyway to fill Tax profile and payment account? Why I can´t get the UPLOAD page  in Windows Phone store but yes, I can get the upload page for Windows Store?  Developer account allow me to publish on both types of stores (win & winP), doesn't it? I've reserved the name in page: 'My App' for Windows Store but in page: Win Phone Dashboard still a link advice the text 'PENDING' linked to Tax profile.

Comment: The Windows and Windows Phone stores are linked but not fully merged. You access them with the same subscription, but will need to set them up separately. If you need help with that you can contact support at http://aka.ms/storesupport .

Comment: Thank you very much. You are helping me learn the basics and at least know where to start, to search and go deep into knowledge about the Msoft Stores, just what I was needing.
I've been publishing apps in Google Play and Apple Store but every store has its own specifications and needed the basics.

Comment: Still can't send WinPHone app. Can configure App and send it in Windows Store (a capture here: http://www.i3net.es/windowsstore_app_ok.jpg).
But if I click Submit App in Windows Phone DashBoard always show this (capture: http://www.i3net.es/windowsphonestore_app_NO_ok.jpg)
But although validation of Account is pending they say this is not required for submit App and configure. Tax and payment not setted but if my app is free we think this not required or may be this is our fault? Why ok in Windows Store and not in WinPHone. App Name is already reserved but only could do it in Win Store. Please

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Sorry we are newbe in Windows Store and we have tackled slowly. From contact support in Msoft they are reviewing our case. Your help was key for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Project->Store->Create App Packages.. from visual studio menu.
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-windows-version-of-your-app